# When composing an email in Gmail, after the first letter of a new line the cursor jumps left

Tags: gmail

So, this is rather difficult to explain, but I will attempt.
Lets say I am starting the body of an email

```
Hello,
```

this is what I type into my keyboard.

```
ello,H
```

This is what shows up.

Another example being

Expected

```
Hi
```

Actual

```
iH
```

After typing the first letter, the cursor jumps left, so as in the last example

```
|H
```

This happens on every new line, and is incredibly frustrating. I wish to know how to fix this.

Comment: This is only happening in Gmail? I suspect some browser add-on.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Is your current browser up to date? Have you tried launching the browser without any add-ons/extensions enabled? Are you using any other "quick key" utility, such as AutoHotkey?

Comment: same issue in Firefox GMail (but not here)

Comment: I find that this happens a lot on various websites usually after a translation has occurred. I've seen it on Reddit, YouTube, and Gmail. 
My guess is that it's related to how the browser acts after the rest of the page has been translated.
It's also really specific and strange, for example if I type an "I" the cursor might jump, but if I type an "a" it might not. And it's also totally repeatable.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue and it was driving me nuts.  Turned out to be the "Millennials to Snake People" Chrome extension.  I disabled it (didn't have to uninstall) and the problem seems to be fixed.

The developer knows about the issue as of a couple weeks ago and is working on it.

Comment: This solution worked for me on macOS.

Comment: This also was caused by a Trump-to-Drumpf extension. Might be common with text replacement extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue too. I tested it out in another browser (Edge) and didn't see the same behaviour. I deleted a couple of extensions from Chrome that I wasn't using, and the issue stopped after I re-launched Chrome. You might want to try out deleting/reinstalling your extensions one by one to figure out which one might be causing this.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue until I uninstalled the Cloud to Butt Redux extension.  Not totally SOL though, the Cloud to Butt Plus extension still works!

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense.  Did you restart the browser after you uninstalled?